# Automatically choose "Try Ubuntu without Installing" after booting from USB Startup Disk

Tags: 10.10, live-usb

I have created a usb bootup stick for 10.10, and reduced the timeout to 0 sec... but after it boots up it shows two options either to install or try ubuntu... I want to avoid this screen and directly go to the tryout mode...

at the first screen at bootup if I press any key,there is an option to select "try Ubuntu without installing",in this case I go to tryout mode directly... I want this behaviour without pressing any key...

any suggestions???

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. For those who don't understand why one would like to do this: In my case I can't get a bootable USB Ubuntu installation to work on my laptop. While a Live-CD on USB works. I can even customize it (install applications which will be available on next restart). I will never use this stick to install Ubuntu but only to use 'test' it. What can be done to skip the 'Try or install' screen and automatically switch to 'try'. Perhaps delete a file or such.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what you want, but if you want it to behave this way you should install Ubuntu on the usb disk rather than installing the Live-CD on it.

Comment: From my understanding of the question, yes, that would be the best way. However, the question isn't that clear as to what exactly they want.

Comment: well i have a feeling that installing non-live ubuntu on the USB hurts its performance more than using a live installation... am i right??? and because i have to use it seldomly only..so thats a reason i dont want to go for the non-live version!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a solution but I think it can get close to what you want.

Make a new Ubuntu install and then, without installing anything, put it back on the usb stick using Remastersys (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remastersys).

Done that you should be able to boot into your Ubuntu from the usb stick without choosing to try or install :)

If Remastersys doesn't do the trick as you want it just a plain install ON the usb stick could work too.

Answer (score 0):

Solution!

use [LiLi](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/home) to create your USB key!

Answer (score 0):

When you create the USB disk using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), there won't be a "Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu" screen after booting.

I don't know *why* this difference exists between Unetbootin and Startup Disk creator, but I just tested this (see my [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52413/method-to-create-a-live-usb-disk-with-persistence-which-actually-works)).

This makes bootup much faster in total.