# "Try Ubuntu" as default startup?

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb

I installed the 64bit version Trusty Tahr to an USB stick with `lili`.

Everything went fine and so far I am happy with the setup, just I would like to prevent the system to ask for installation after startup. Just keep the "Try Ubuntu" option as default.

Is this possible and how? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Visit: http://askubuntu.com/questions/32484/how-to-boot-from-ubuntu-live-usb-with-try-ubuntu-directly & http://askubuntu.com/questions/15470/automatically-choose-try-ubuntu-without-installing-after-booting-from-usb-star

Answer (score 1):

Is your install persistent? Do the following, If not Persistent leave off the word persistent in the code below.

Go to the root folder of your Live USB
Enter the syslinux directory, (or for UNetbootin the root directory).
Make the syslinux.cfg file writeable
Replace the contents of the file syslinux.cfg with:

Code:

```
default persistent
label persistent
  say Booting a persistent Ubuntu session...
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash noprompt --
```

Shutdown, remove CD, reboot.